# Entry Validation with tkinter

Tags: python, validation, tkinter

When I am trying to enter something , its just going to Invalid block, without letting me enter any key. I understand, I can get rid of it by using other options 'focus' , 'focusout' etc. But I want it to work with key :

```
from tkinter import *
import re

def validate_email(P):
   # master.errormsg.config(text='')
   x = re.match(r"[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+", P)
   print(P)
   errormsg.config(text='')
   emailentry.focus_set()
   return x != None


def invalid_email(P):
    errormsg.config(text='Invalid Email Address')
    emailentry.focus_set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = Tk()
    errormsg = Label(master,text='', fg='red')
    errormsg.pack()
    L1 = Label(master, text='Enter Email Address')
    L1.pack(side=LEFT)
    vcmd = (master.register(validate_email), '%P')
    invcmd = (master.register(invalid_email), '%P')
    emailentry = Entry(master, validate="focusout", validatecommand=vcmd,  
    invalidcommand=invcmd)
    emailentry.pack()
    Button(master, text="Login").pack()
    master.mainloop()
```

Comment: oops!! change code with validate = key....I am refering to 'key'

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner myself but in running your code and debugging it looks when you use 'key', the entry field is grabbing the value of the key that you are currently pressing on your keyboard. Your two functions are evaluating the value and it's failing every time because it's of coarse not an email address.

If you look in the console you can see that print(P) is printing out whichever key you happen to be pressing at the time.

Comment: Close, but not quite. `P` will be the value of the entry if the edit (the key being pressed) is allowed. It just so happens that since every key is rejected, P is always a single character. Under slightly different circumstances, `P` could be a long string (such as if the entry is given a default value before editing is allowed).